# Including node libraries (unirest) in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, unirest

I'd like to make requests to the [twinword text classification api](https://www.twinword.com/api/text-classification.php), however I can see that it's designed to be used with  [unirest in node.js](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/nodejs-1). Would it be possible to do this inside a chrome extension? If so, how might I go about doing it? I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to API calls - if there are any examples of chrome extensions which have done something similar, I'd love to take a look.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's just a wrapper around XHR/fetch so you should be able to use the underlying XHR/fetch directly or find a different wrapper that's distributed as a single browser-compatible library.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to find out how the request is structured? Unirest accepts a series of .post, .header, .send and .end inputs, and I’m having trouble translating that into the correct syntax (url) for fetch or xhr. Do you think it’s as simple as as interpreting the unirest documentation for node? I’ve taken a look and I can’t seem to figure everything out. Cheers for the help.

Comment: I haven't used unirest. I think even if you won't find a tutorial or documentation on conversion to XHR/fetch, it should be just like any other standard request so it'd be still beneficial to know the universal basic approach for which there should be lots of good info.

Comment: Okay thank you! For reasearch purposes, what would this sort of thing typically be referred to as? API request structure or something? Just so that I can go about learning the universal basic approach

Comment: "How to make API requests with fetch or XHR in javascript" seems like a good start. Also use devtools network inspector to see what you're sending and receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use node modules in chrome extension directly  because your script file must be a single .js without any import or require but there is a way.
you can use webpack to generate a single js file of your code 
webpack looks to your code and when sees a require goes to the file and puts the code in a js file i have a template for chrome extension in my github :

[Chrome-Extension-Template](https://github.com/payamnaghdy/Chrome-Extension-Template)